# How to change pdf file resolution

Tags: pdf, mpdf

I use mpdf to output pdf files from my application. Following manual I am creating HTML code that is converted into pdf. I noticed that width of pdf file is about 800px. Is there any possibility to change it? I would like to include images 1200px width into document.

Comment: Your assumptions are not correct, PDF is a vector format, so there is no "resolution" for PDF files. There is however a resolution for each raster image included in a PDF file, and there is no limitations or restrictions for  those.